# Como criar um script no Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, script, opencv

Preciso fazer um script para rodar o comando abaixo no terminal diversas vezes:

```
opencv_createsamples -img toras/toras_00001.jpg -bg negativas/negativas.txt -info positivas1/positivas1.txt -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 100 -bgcolor 0
```

O que vai mudar cada vez que o comando roda são estes parâmetros:

```
-img toras/toras_00001.jpg
-info positivas1/positivas1.txt
```

Onde tem 1, vira 2, 3, 4, 5... até 492

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Fazendo uma comparação com C++, acredito que seja algo do tipo:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 492; i++)
{
    opencv_createsamples -img "toras/toras_0000"+to_string(i)+".jpg" -bg negativas/negativas.txt -info "positivas"+to_string(i)+"/positivas"+to_string(i)+".txt" -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 100 -bgcolor 0
}
```

Porém ainda não descobri como escrever algo assim em bash...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0HY1crw7

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Perdão a ignorância, mas como fez? Minha pergunta é muito básica para alguém negativar??

Comment: Eu utilizei o comando `seq` para gerar uma sequência de *0* a *492*; Para formar o valor *00001*, utilizei o `printf`, para o *Zero-Padding*. Neste comando, definir que ele terá que complementar com o número "0" até completar 4 dígitos (0001, 0010, 0100, 1000). P.S.: O `for` funciona tal qual em GoLang. Ele vai percorrer todos os valores gerados pelo `seq`

Comment: Sobre os votos negativos, eu não sei dizer o porquê (não negativei). Talvez as pessoas não tenham entendido a pergunta e resolveram negativar; ou talvez seja por outros motivos. Recomendo o link https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=negativo. Sobre o voto para fechamento, sinceramente não entendi. A pergunta está dentro do escopo.

Comment: Entendi, muito bom o teu raciocínio para gerar a numerção, não tinha pensado nisso. Eu tinha pensado em usar condicionais, mas ía dar mais trabalho, além de eu não ter noção de como se programa em bash. Só fiz uma modificação em: filename=$(printf %04d $i), substituí o 4 por 5. Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve!

Em primeiro lugar você tem zeros significativos na nomenclatura dos seus arquivos:

```
-img toras/toras_00001.jpg
```

São 5 algarismos, então é importante manter os 5 algarismos quando o seu laço passar dos 10, dos 100.
Então, o primeiro passo, depois do laço de repetição, é definir uma variável onde armazene-se seu número de 5 algarismos.

Depois você faz a chamada dos comando variando o número completo.

```
for i in {1..492}
do
    n=`printf "%05.0f" $i`
    opencv_createsamples -img "toras/toras_$n.jpg" -bg "negativas/negativas$i.txt" -info positivas1/positivas1.txt -maxxangle 0.5 -maxyangle 0.5 -maxzangle 0.5 -num 100 -bgcolor 0
done
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!